# operation parameter must be str in sql/python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

```
import sqlite3, time, datetime, random, random

class DatabaseManager(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.conn.execute('pragma foreign_keys = on')
        self.conn.commit()
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()


    def query(self, arg):
        self.c.execute(arg)
        self.conn.commit()
        return self.c

    def fetch(self):
        self.c.fetchall()
        self.conn.commit()
        return self.c

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()



dbmgr = DatabaseManager("connect.db")



while 1 > 0:

    def quantity():
        x = 1
        file = open("john.txt", "r")

        for line in file:
            x = random.randint(100,10000000)
            func = "INSERT INTO test (playerNAME) VALUES (?, ?)", line, x
            dbmgr.query(func)
```

You can ignore the while 1 > 0, that was part of the code I deleted to specifically ask my question. When I call the function quantity() (in another part of code I also deleted for the questions sake), I get an error that states:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\senarsky.CAL\Documents\2016Sem2\Sqlite-connect.py", line 210, in 
    quantity()
  File "C:\Users\senarsky.CAL\Documents\2016Sem2\Sqlite-connect.py", line 68, in quantity
    dbmgr.query(func)
  File "C:\Users\senarsky.CAL\Documents\2016Sem2\Sqlite-connect.py", line 14, in query
    self.c.execute(arg)
**ValueError: operation parameter must be str**

I am not sure how to make the func line a string without using insecure sql formatting...

Comment: `x` is an int. your parameters must be str

Comment: a simple sanitation could be to add `args = map(str, args)` in your `query` function

Comment: @njzk2 Where would I add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your query parameters in a tuple:

```
query = "INSERT INTO test (playerNAME) VALUES (?, ?)"
parameters = (line, x)
```

Modify the `query` method to accept both query and parameters:

```
def query(self, query, params=None):
    self.c.execute(query, params)
    self.conn.commit()
    return self.c
```

And then call as:

```
dbmgr.query(query, parameters)
```

Comment: So what are the params=None and params variables for?

Comment: @Dominico909 this is where your query parameters would be passed in - values for the `?` placeholders.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was a bit confused more at what params=None is for.